# jQuery uncaught reference error - element is not defined

Tags: jquery, undefined, parallax

I implemented the following plugin in into a drupal website https://github.com/linnett/backgroundVideo following their instructions to the T.

I am receiving a `jQuery uncaught reference error: element is not defined` error. This is my [site](http://link.disadmin.webfactional.com/en).

Comment: `jQuery(element).backgroundVideo({...` the element variable is not defined.

Comment: Where do you define element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `element` is supposed to be a reference to your video element.

```
var element = "#TheVideoElementId";
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the github project and also to the examples which are provided, `element` is just a placeholder for your `<video>` wrapper. So if you've copied the example, you just have to use the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#my-video').backgroundVideo({
            $videoWrap: $('#cmn-video-demo3__container'),
            $outerWrap: $('.block-block block-block-10')    
        });
    });
```